# Perl one-liner to add a string at the end of file name

Tags: linux, perl

I have some HTML and JavaScript files in a directory. I want to append "_backup" at the end of each JavaScript (name.js) file. What would be the [one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program) for it?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you want to do that in perl?

Comment: Because I'm curious how would one do that in Perl :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick your poison:

1. **`File::Copy`**

   ```
   use File::Copy 'move';
   for ( glob "*.js" ){  # Platform independent
       move( $_, "${_}_backup" ) or warn "Failed to copy '$_'";
   }
   ```
2. [`rename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) function

   ```
   for ( glob "*.js" ){   # Not platform independent
       rename( $_, "${_}_backup" ) or warn "Failed to copy '$_'";
   }
   ```
3. The *nix `rename` utility

   ```
   $ rename .js .js_backup *.js
   ```

Comment: oh, thanks for `${_}` <- I always forget about this feature in strings

Answer (score 1):

-i option creates the backup file with the given suffix, and then you give an empty script.

```
perl -i_backup -p -e "" *.js; rm *.js
```

that's actually a two-liners

Thanks to [Zaid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15875133/257635):

```
perl -e 'rename($_,$_."_backup") for (glob "*.js");'
```

Comment: It creates another file named "name.html_backup" and "name.js_backup". I don't want to create a copy, I want to rename it. Plus I don't want to touch the HTML files, I want to rename only JS files.

Comment: Yep the edited version works, but as you said it's a two liner.

Answer (score 0):

This a slightly long line, but it is a Perl one-liner!

I assume you want files named

```
abc.js
def.js
dog.js
```

to be renamed to

```
abc_backup.js
def_backup.js
dog_backup.js

perl -e 'for(@ARGV) { ($bname)=/(.*)\.js/; rename $_, "$1_backup.js"; } ' *js
```

Most Linux distributions include a program "rename" which is actually written in Perl and does renaming operations like this; see `man rename`.